# Converting character string representing a timestamp to a timestamp data type with specific format in SQL

Tags: sql, toad-data-point

I have a column in my SQL database where timestamps are stored as character strings in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'. For example, '2006-01-01 00:00:00.000000'.

Now, I need to convert these character strings into timestamp data types with a specific format, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'. For example, '1/1/2006 12:00:00 AM'. It's important to remove the '0'-es from the result.

I've tried using the `TO_TIMESTAMP()` function along with `TO_CHAR()`, but I'm not getting the desired output. Here's what I've tried:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('2006-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') AS formatted_timestamp;
```

However, this query doesn't give me the exact output I'm looking for. The result the script above is giving is this:

```
01/01/2006 12:00:00 AM
```

Can someone please help me with the correct SQL query to achieve this conversion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What result does your query get you?

Comment: It's populating as '01/01/2006 12:00:00 AM' but my expected output is 1/1/2006 12:00:00 AM

Comment: One thing I'm missing here is clrearly indicated DB you're using. Another thing is that timestamp has no format. Basically what you have here is a string to string reformat. This can be done with casting to timestamp or without it. Just please remember dates are numbers and do not have formats as such. Formated is the string representation of the date. Assuming this is Oracle you need to use DS for date short. Have a look at https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-date-format/

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Following statement works in most of the SQL databases, when a string is in proper date format. May work for yours as well.

Also note that, not all the time standards in capital letter as you specified in format, like months have `MM` whereas minutes have `mm`

```
FORMAT(CAST([column] AS DATETIME), 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt')
```

You can use either DATETIME or DATETIME2 in the `CAST` function

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting 'invalid datatype' error

Comment: This would get him 2006-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 which is not what he wants.

Comment: Note that DATETIME2 isn't a common SQL data type.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the result without the zeroes you need to add FM to the parts where you want to exclude the zeroes. FM suppresses blanks and zeroes. Do it like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('2006-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'FMMM/FMDD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') AS formatted_timestamp
```

Comment: I tried this one but it's only changing the month part I still see my DD as 01

Comment: Are you sure you've added FM to your DD? It should look like this: FMDD.

Comment: Yep this is what is gave 'FMMM/FMDD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'  and I'm getting 1/01/2006 12:00:00 AM

Comment: You are using Oracle right? You haven't added a tag, I guessed based on your script.

Comment: Can you try SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('2006-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'FMFM/FMDD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') AS formatted_timestamp